# Scope join table to build new association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I would like to scope a join table and create a new association.

In my join table (PrestaMission), I store two values (:assigned and :proposed). So I would like to create a new association to create two has_many in my model.

I give you the code, it will be clearest.

The model Mission :

```
class Mission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :presta_missions, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The join table (PrestaMission)

```
class PrestaMission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :mission

  scope :assigned, -> { where(assigned: true) }
  scope :proposed, -> { where(proposed: true) }
end
```

And the model Keyper (which is one of the client of PrestaMission)

```
class Keyper < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :presta_missions, as: :client, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :missions, through: :presta_missions

  has_many :assigned_prestas, -> { where(assigned: true) }, :class_name => 'PrestaMission'
  has_many :assigned_missions, through: :assigned_prestas

  has_many :proposed_prestas, -> { where(proposed: true) }, :class_name => 'PrestaMission'
  has_many :proposed_missions, through: :proposed_prestas
end
```

But this script to link association is currently not working. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I found an elegant solution to solve that problem :

```
  has_many :presta_missions, as: :client, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :missions, :through => :presta_missions do
    def assigneds
      where("presta_missions.assigned = ?", true)
    end
    def proposeds
      where("presta_missions.proposed = ?", true)
    end
  end
```

And to call this association you can now use the following command

```
@keyper.missions.proposeds
OR
@keyper.missions.assigneds
```

Make good use and have fun !!